# How to merge duplicate elements in a list while adding their "coefficient"?

Tags: python, list

I'm writing a function 'simplify' to simplify polynomials so that `simplify("2xy-yx")` can return `"xy"`, `simplify("-a+5ab+3a-c-2a")`can return `"-c+5ab"` and so on.

I am at the stage where I have broken the polynomials into multiple monomials as elements for a list and have separated the coefficient of the monomials and the letter (variable) parts.

For instance

```
input = '3xy+y-2x+2xy'
```

My process gives me:

```
Var = ['xy', 'y', 'x', 'xy']
Coe = ['+3', '+1', '-2', '+2']
```

What I want to do is to merge the same monomials and add up their corresponding coefficients in the other list simultaneously.

My code was:

```
Play1 = Letter[:]
Play2 = Coe[:]
for i in range(len(Play1) - 1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(Play1)):
        if Play1[i] == Play1[j]:
            Letter.pop(j)
            Coe[i] = str(int(Play2[i]) + int(Play2[j]))
            Coe.pop(j)
```

But this seems to only work with lists where each duplicate element appears no more than twice. For instance, input of "-a+5ab+3a-c-2a" gives me:

```
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

I thought of using `set`, but that will change the order.

What's the best way to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: `j = re.findall(r"[\w]+", i)` gives `['3xy', 'y', '2x', '2xy']`

Comment: @Rohit-Pandey Regex is truly amazing. I will definitely learn it once I have a better grasp of the fundamentals of Python. How regex can do, IMO, such a complex thing in such a concise way is beyond me. Could you tell me what `r"[\w]+"` is doing please?

Comment: The `\w` means "any word character" which usually means alphanumeric (letters, numbers, regardless of case) plus underscore (_). and `+` means repetitions of `\w`

Comment: TRY THIS ONE [link](https://repl.it/repls/BelatedHardtofindInstance)

Comment: full use of regex. @Bowen Liu

Comment: @Rohit-Pandey Thank you so much for your explanation and the link to your code. I will play around to see what's what. So `re.findall(r"[\w]+", i)` will find all the words in the list `Play` and concatenate with its element of the same index? And how did you get to learn regex so well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine your lists with `zip()` for easier processing, and create a new list:

```
newVar = []
newCoe = []

for va, co in zip(Var, Coe):

    # try/except (EAFP) is very Pythonic
    try:
        # See if this var is seen
        ind = newVar.index(va)

        # Yeah, seen, let's add the coefficient
        newCoe[ind] = str(int(newCoe[ind]) + int(co))

    except ValueError:
        # No it's not seen, add both to the new lists
        newVar.append(va)
        newCoe.append(co)
```

Because all items are processed in their original order, as well as using list appending instead of hash tables (like `set` and `dict`), the order is preserved.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Your code is very clean and easy to follow. How did you get this done so quickly is beyond me. Hopefully one day I will be there. This is amazing, just what I needed. And as for the order, it can change as long as the corresponding coefficient changes with it. And as for your comment, can I assume that `try/except` is more Pythonic than `if/else`? Thanks again.

Comment: And an additional question (I know I shall probably make a new post for a new question, but since we are already here): when I combine the two lists using your method: `list(map(lambda x,y: y+x, newVar, newCoe))`, the result I get is `['0a', '+5ab', '-1c']`, what is Pythonic way to delete the item with 0 and and change `-1` or `+1` to just `-` or `+`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically a use-case where dict come in handy :

```
from collections import defaultdict

Var = ['xy', 'y', 'x', 'xy']
Coe = ['+3', '+1', '-2', '+2']

polynom = defaultdict(int)
for var, coeff in zip(Var, Coe):
    polynom[var] += int(coeff)

Var, Coe = list(polynom.keys()), list(polynom.values())
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. But could you tell me what the step `polynom = defaultdict(int)` does please?

Answer (score 1):

### Your input was:

```
input = '3xy+y-2x+2xy'
```

### You reached till:

```
Var = ['xy', 'y', 'x', 'xy']
Coe = ['+3', '+1', '-2', '+2']
```

### Use below code to get --> `+5xy-y-2x`

```
def varCo(Var, Coe):

    aa = {}
    for k, i in enumerate(Var):
        if i in aa: aa[i] += int(Coe[k])
        else      : aa[i] = "" if int(Coe[k]) == 1 else "-" if int(Coe[k]) == -1 else int(Coe[k])
    aa = "".join([("" if "-" in str(v) else "+") + str(v)+i for i, v in aa.items() if v != 0])
    return aa

Var = ['xy', 'y', 'x', 'xy']
Coe = ['+3', '-1', '-2', '+2']

print (varCo(Var, Coe))

#Result --> +5xy-y-2x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was trying to give dict a go but wasn't successful. An additional question for the next step:  for another input, the result I get is `['0a', '+5ab', '-1c']`, what is Pythonic way to delete the item with 0 and and change `-1` or `+1` to just `-` or `+`. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @BowenLiu, I have edited the code
Added -> if else added to check if the value is 1 and ignore values from the dict in list comprehension to avoid "0".

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:**
with using `regex`

```
import re
# a = '3xy+y-2x+2xy'
a = "-a+5ab+3a-c-2a"
i = re.findall(r"[\w]+", a)
j = re.findall(r"[\W]+", a)
if len(i)!=len(j):
  j.insert(0,'+')
d = []
e = []
for k in i:
  match = re.match(r"([0-9]+)([a-z]+)", k, re.I)
  if match:
    items = match.groups()
    d.append(items[0])
    e.append(items[1])
  else:
      d.append('1')
      e.append(k)
print(e)
f = []
for ii,jj in zip(j,d):
  f.append(ii+jj)
print(f)
```

Input:

```
a = "-a+5ab+3a-c-2a"
```

Output:

```
['a', 'ab', 'a', 'c', 'a']
['-1', '+5', '+3', '-1', '-2']
```

Input:

```
a = '3xy+y-2x+2xy'
```

Output:

```
['xy', 'y', 'x', 'xy']
['+3', '+1', '-2', '+2']
```